# Произойдет ли загрузка класса только при объявлении переменной?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

Знаю, что загрузка класса происходит точно при такой записи `A a = new A();`.
И при обращении к статическому контенту класса,
к примеру, если напишем `А.SomeStatic`.

Произойдет ли загрузка класса только при объявлении переменной `A a;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимо различать загрузку класса/интерфейса и  инициализацию (также есть промежуточный большой этап - линковка, но его рассматривать не будем). **Загрузка** (loading) - это процесс поиска бинарного представления класса/интерфейса по соответствующему имени и создание этого класса/интерфейса из этого представления. **Инициализация** заключается в исполнении всех блоков/методов инициализации класса/интерфейса.

Спецификация не дает точных указаний по загрузке класса/интерфейса - этот процесс может быть выполнен заранее (lazy loading), либо непосредственно перед линковкой и инициализацией.

По поводу инициализации в спецификации чётко прописаны условия её выполнения:

- при выполнении следующих JVM инструкций: `new`, `getstatic`, `putstatic` или `invokestatic`,
- при выполнении методов рефлексии из Java API (методы класса `Class` и использование классов из пакета `java.lang.reflect`),
- инициализация производных классов,
- при старте JVM, если класс содержит метод `main()`.

Объявление ссылки на класс `A` не приводит к выполнению хотя бы одного из вышеприведенных условий, поэтому инициализация класса выполнена не будет.

Для просмотра порядка загрузки классов можно использовать опцию `-verbose:class`.

Более подробно по этому вопросу можно ознакомиться в спецификации [Chapter 5. Loading, Linking, and Initializing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5)